# Can't upload images with Magento 1.4 on Windows/IIS

Tags: windows, iis, magento

Everything else works in Magento 1.4 but I can't upload images. Running on Windows/IIS. I know it isn't officially supported but seems odd that everything works but something as simple as image uploads.

Tried updating the media path and that is correct. Also updated permissions on directories, but nothing has worked.

Any other ideas to get this to work?

thanks

Comment: What kind of errors are you seeing?

Comment: Could do with more info about what you're observing when this doesn't work?

Comment: I go to upload a file, it says uploading. And then will always come up with the Red Error message "File was not uploaded". 

Even installed the "No Flash Image Uploader" which replaces the flash uploader with a browse button and it still doesn't work. 

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Tobias+Renger/extension/1756/no-flash-uploader/reviews/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this? 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/19925/
(essentially set permissions on TEMP directory where images are saved during upload)

Comment: Thanks..wasn't tmp permissions but was related to tmp directory!

Comment: Changed the tmp dir from 

upload_tmp_dir="C:\DOCUME~1\UserName\LOCALS~1\Temp\php\upload"

to

upload_tmp_dir=C:\tmp

And it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this problem happen when you have **Basic Authentication** on the entire site. Everything works, except image upload. I didn't find a solution other than removing the basic auth temporarily when needing to upload images.